# Primefaces chart popup bigger when click anywhere on the chart?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2, charts

I know that there is an interactive chart which use to click on the bar or pie elements to popup more information. However I want that when I click on everywhere inside the chart, it will popup a new window which displays bigger view of the chart. Any suggestions please?
I tried to use popup window but I use for loop to display my charts, the dialog isn't able to display the correct chart(it displays the latest chart in the list and does not content values). Here is what I did:

```
<c:forEach  items="${dashboardBean.barModel}" var="barChart">
                                <p:column>
                            <p:chart type="bar" model="#{barChart}" style="height:400px">
                                <p:commandButton type="button" value="Export"
                                                 onclick="PF('dlg1').show();"/>
                                    </p:chart>
                                <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg1"
                                          height="450px" width="800px" >
                                    <p:chart type="bar" model="#{barChart}"/>
                                </p:dialog>
                                </p:column>
                            </c:forEach>
```

And here is how the popup chart looks like:
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Why not use the chart zoom functionality?

Comment: Hi because in my dashboard has many small charts so i want to popup windows when click than zoom

Comment: Then add a plain javascript onclick eventhandler to the chart  that opens a dialog in which a bigger chart is loaded. Which one is to be passed in one way or another. If you experiment and have actual concrete code with errors, please get back to us

Comment: @Kukeltje hi i updated the question on the problem i have to open dialog for bigger chart

Comment: On click on the button you can set the clicked barModel as a property on the bean (for example with an actionlistener with parameter), and then use update="ifOfDialog". And make the dialog show chart for this selected barModel. And remove type="button" and use oncomplete instead

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar sorry I'm not sure what you mean. do u have an example for it?

Comment: Maybe take a step back from this concrete problem and learn about more generic master-datail solutions. lots of those in the PF showcase and on stackoverflow. I get the impression you lack that (basic) knowledge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

100% untested, so take it as an idea. Make selectedBarChart a property on the bean.

```
<c:forEach  items="${dashboardBean.barModel}" var="barChart">
    <p:column>
        <p:chart type="bar" model="#{barChart}" style="height:400px">
            <p:commandButton value="Export" update=":dlg1" oncomplete="PF('dlg1').show();">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{dashboardBean.selectedBarChart}" value="#{barChart}" />
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:chart>                         
    </p:column>
</c:forEach>

<p:dialog id="dlg1" widgetVar="dlg1" appendTo="@(body)" height="450px" width="800px" >
    <p:chart type="bar" model="#{dashboardBean.selectedBarChart}"/>
</p:dialog>
```

I think c:forEach must be replaced with ui:repeat, but not sure

Comment: like stated... 'Basic' master-detail stuff ;-)

Comment: hi, for some reasons, it could not set the value of selectedbarchart, it returns Null when i called it in dialog